# Firebase get the last id - limitToLast not working - android

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to get the last id of my messages node, but it's not getting the last one. For example, my last id is 12, but it's always returning the id of item 10. My code is like this:

```
final Query query = firebase.orderByChild("messageId").limitToLast(1);
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { 

      Log.i("MessagesFrag","snapshot: "+dataSnapshot.getValue()+""); 

   }

   public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {}

});
```

It returns something like this:

```
{10={chatId=6, time=Wed Apr 13 22:20:43 EDT 2016, message=hi, user=123, messageId=10}}
```

It should return:

```
{12={chatId=6, time=Wed Apr 13 22:29:02 EDT 2016, message=I am fine, user=1234, messageId=12}}
```

My data is something like this:

```
messages
  9:
    chatId: "6"
    message: "hi"
    messageId: "9"
    time: "Wed Apr 13 22:29:02 EDT 2016"
    user: "123"
  10:
    chatId: "6"
    message: "hello"
    messageId: "10"
    time: "Wed Apr 13 22:29:02 EDT 2016"
    user: "1234"
  11:
    chatId: "6"
    message: "how are you?"
    messageId: "11"
    time: "Wed Apr 13 22:29:02 EDT 2016"
    user: "123"
  12:
    chatId: "6"
    message: "I am fine"
    messageId: "12"
    time: "Wed Apr 13 22:29:02 EDT 2016"
    user: "1234"
```

In addition to that, When I change "LimitToLast" to "LimitToFirst" (thatshould get the first one), it does not get the first element I have (node 1), it gets the node 10 too.

Does anyone know what can be the problem?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is `orderByChild` , since the messages are ordered in a numerical way no need to order them again. try this :

```
 FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        // change this to your databae ref
        final DatabaseReference messages = database
                .getReference("XXXX")
                .child("XXXX"); // change this to your databae ref

        messages .limitToLast(1).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    // access last message
                    DataSnapshot messageSnapShot= dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator().next();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```